# Are Futurama comic books canon?

Tags: comics, futurama, canon

I recently noticed that Futurama has a comic book series. I was wondering if the Futurama comics are events that really happened in the Futurama universe or are they fake events simulated similar to the What If Machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comic somewhat continues the series itself.

[From wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama_Comics)

> Futurama Comics is a comic book series published by Bongo Comics and
>   based on the television series Futurama. During the production hiatus between 2003 and 2006 it was the only new Futurama material being made.

[From wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongo_Comics)

> Bongo Comics Group is a comic book publishing company founded in 1993
>   by Steve and Cindy Vance, Bill Morrison, and Simpsons and Futurama
>   creator Matt Groening. It publishes comics related to the animated
>   television series The Simpsons, Futurama and SpongeBob SquarePants;
>   along with original material.

The comic expands on the series a bit, with more support for other minor characters. It has about 30 pages and tells one story, like one episode in the series. It follows the basic series humor, like the captions before the title of the comic book (Issue 3: NEW VERSION 3.0! Issue 6: PRINTED IN MINT CONDITION! Issue 24: WHAT IF YOU BOUGHT THIS COMIC?). I have also heard that the captions are different for the same issue, probably different printing versions for global shipment.

If you are referring to the episode *Anthology of Interest I* where the *What-If Machine* is first revealed, it continues in the comic book, issue *Anthology of Interest II* with different events. It also gets involved with Bender on an occasion (I will not spoil the comic book here), which happens before the aforementioned issue.

Comment: That they have similar styles doesn't really allude to its canon-status. References from the TV series to the comics would. Or statements from the makers of the TV series.

Comment: @bitmask The fact that Matt Groening owns Bongo Comics has to account for a wee bit of cannon.

Comment: I didn't know that, you should add this to your answer.

Comment: @bitmask Noted, updated.

Comment: I should point out that the comic book did continue from a plot. The plot was about Farnsworth's unpaid taxes from the 10 years he lied, continuing from the episode Farnsworth turned himself in to the Sunset Squad.

Answer (score 3):

The TV show itself doesn't really put much store in continuity, so I don't really think you can hope for any more from the comic books.

Comment: **seriously??** of course it does!

Answer (score 2):

The Futurama comics are written by '[Bongo Comics Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongo_Comics)', which was founded by Steve and Cindy Vance, Bill Morrison and [Matt Groening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Groening). Being the creator of the TV series, if Groening was also the creator of the comics, I think this would give them more evidence to be canon.

But that's not the end of it.

This from [The Infoshere](http://theinfosphere.org/Canon)

> **The Canon of Futurama is what is accepted by its fans to be "truth" in its universe. This article does not describe what is, but merely what fans think is canon.**

Also some evidence in the stories against.

> Some details that have yet to be provided by episodes can be loosely considered canon, however due to there being an **Xmas comic set in the same year as an Xmas episode** and a number of fourth wall breaks, the plots are generally considered non-canon.

My opinion: I would say Futurama Comics are canon. Even if the comics have a mixed up story, the episodes themselves aren't all inline and making complete sense.

Comment: Well, I guess canonicity is typically something defined by the creators -- not the fans -- of a given franchise (or in Lucas terms: *Everything that sells*).